# Why there is no password setting in my Drupal website when a user registers?

Tags: drupal-7

When I made my own website I tried to register with a username. But on the register page, there is only a username label and an email label.How can I set the password?

I developed my website with drupal7. Is there a way that allows a user to set their password by themselves rather than by admin?

Comment: You could ask on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as pointed out by @assylas, this rather belongs to drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the LoginToboggan module can do everything you need.

```
The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:

*Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.

*Allow users to login immediately. Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
*The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.

*Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.

*Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.

*Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.

*Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.

*Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.

*Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt for important information on configuring this feature!).

*Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)
```

Source : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/enable-password-and-confirm-password-fields-in-registration-form